# UNet : ClientRpc doesn't get executed in the for loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting used to this site and i thank every one that helped me so far .My problem this time is a CLient RPC that doesn't get executed in the for loop this the code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class CardSpawnerFirstNew : NetworkBehaviour {




public override void OnStartServer(){
    distributeCards ();

} 

IEnumerator Mycoroutine (bool CardDistribution){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
    if (ClientScene.ready) {
        Debug.Log ("the if statement worked");
        NetworkManager NetM;
        NetM = NetworkManager.singleton;

        List<GameObject> Cards;

        Cards = NetM.spawnPrefabs;
        Debug.Log (Cards.Count);
        for ( int i = 0;i<4;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                GameObject currentGameObject = Cards [Random.Range (0, Cards.Count)];

                Cards.Remove (currentGameObject);
                Debug.Log (currentGameObject);
                Vector2 currentPosition = positionCalculator (i,j);
                RpcInstantiateCards (currentPosition, currentGameObject);

            }


        }




    }
}


public Vector2 positionCalculator (int I,int J){

    Transform startPositionTransform;
    Vector2 position, finalPosition;
    List<Transform> startPositionsList;
    Vector2 Increment = new Vector2 (1.41f, 0f);

    NetworkManager netM = NetworkManager.singleton;
    startPositionsList = netM.startPositions;

    startPositionTransform = startPositionsList [I];
    position = startPositionTransform.position;
    finalPosition = position + J * Increment;

    return finalPosition;


}
[Server]
public bool distributeCards(){
    bool cardDistribution = false;

    cardDistribution = true;

    StartCoroutine ("Mycoroutine",cardDistribution);

    return cardDistribution;
}

[ClientRpc]
public void RpcInstantiateCards (Vector2 position,GameObject card){
    Debug.Log ("The RPC worked !!!");
    Instantiate (card, position, Quaternion.identity);
}

}
```

this is what the console shows [Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tlvX.png)

what i'mtring todois to call the RPc every time the for loop loops but instead of that it passes the RPC and goes on for the next iteration .

I appreciate every help .thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work.
You cannot call an RPC method more than one time per frame, the network can't support that call speed.
Inastead put another for-loop in your RPC and call it once.